# JQuery Mobile, load then change possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to load an external page and insert it in my HTML. Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#idButton").click( function() {
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("load","file:///url/to/my/HTMLFILE");
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change","#pageID");
    });
  });
});
```

When I execute it, I need to press the button twice before it change my page. How can I fix this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you have wrong syntax. Please check if this works for you.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#idButton").click( function() {
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("load","file:///url/to/my/HTMLFILE");
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change","#pageID");
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried it, it's the same result. I need to press the button twice, maybe the first time it tries to change the page, it is not fully loaded ?